# The Relationship between Coulombs Law and Electric Fields

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

Im trying to understand the relationship between Coulomb's Law and Electric Fields. According to Coulomb's Law opposite charges attract (apply forces on one another)and the way I think about it is that this arises from the electric fields around the charges. But my confusion comes when I look at how common electric fields are drawn for two opposite charges, I dont see how the force vectors  apply to the negative charge (since electric field lines are always drawn form the point of view of a small + charge). Would the vector lines be considered some "two-way force vector" which doesn't make sense I know) as I have drawn below with the blue arrows being the direction in reference to the - charge? If someone could help me visualize this better I would be greatly appreciative!

[image]

[[image]]

Edit:

A user left a comment on my this question which made me think maybe this illustration is more accurate if one is truly on considering these two charges.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The lines you have are for the combination of both charges.  A charge does not feel its own field, but only the field of the other charges.  So you need to examine the field lines due to one of the charges to see how it interacts with the other charge.

Comment: I see your point, but how does that work then? Wouldnt every charge just be link via electric fields with each other??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by link, but charge 1 feels the field due to charge 2 and vice-versa. The lines you have would be felt by a third test charge.

Comment: but if Charge 1 and Charge 2 both have there fields at the same time, wouldnt they combine and be graphically how i have shown? And then how do they exert forces on each-other then?

Comment: The field lines for a single charge are radial lines.  That is what a second charge would feel.  The lines you have drawn is what a third charge would feel from the two charges you show.

Comment: Sorry to make you repeat yourself again Bill, I think Im starting to realize what you are saying. See my Edit to my original post...is that a more accurate illustration? Since +Q does not experience its own field and vise versa with -Q

Comment: Yes, that is a reasonable representation.